# Creating Embeded PDF with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf, pdf-generation

Hello first of all I'm noob in python don't get mad please.

/ FIXED /

I'm asking you guys for help to how can I do this.

Thank you.

this is what I want to do

https://youtu.be/TBpwJY9jzoc

SOURCE :

*/ REDACTED /*

Thanks Guys I figured out.

Comment: Could you please demonstrate what you have tried and where you are stuck? showing a code that someone else wrote and asking us to alter it for your needs is not what OS is for.

Comment: @manandearth I have tried to add picture instead of text but I couldn't and I tried to merge the pdf file that I create with this and another pdf file that I created and added picture in it but unsuccssfully it did not worked and I tried to add extra option in this source that Mr. Didier Stevens did but I couldn't. The extra option that I want to add is instead of text I want to add picture in to pdf. I can share a demo video what does this tool does and what I want to do thanks. I also tried to add this but it did not worked. pastebin.com/nvttwe6z

Comment: @manandearth https://youtu.be/TBpwJY9jzoc I showed what I want to do. thank you